# What's the currently recommended way to install node.js on Debian?

Tags: debian, node.js, javascript

I've found a few different methods on the web, but some of the articles are quite old, and I'm concerned that the methods they describe have been superceded.

Can anyone tell me what the currently recommended method, to best utilise package management etc?

Answer (score 16):

The official [node.js github page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) has a rundown for all distros, Debian included.  They recommend installing from source:

```
apt-get install python g++ wget libssl-dev
mkdir /tmp/nodejs && cd /tmp/nodejs
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*
./configure
make
make test
make install
```

Remember that installing from source will definitely get you the latest software, however sometimes it is more difficult to uninstall all files attached to a specific project.  In order to avoid this, use `checkinstall` to build yourself a quick package.

I was able to build a .deb package on Ubuntu by following the guide [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702211840/http://apptob.org/).  This should probably also work for Debian too ;-)

Comment: Dead link :( - used to be like this https://web.archive.org/web/20120702211840/http://apptob.org/

Comment: Thanks for noticing that!  I've changed the link to the archived version.  (kinda funny that the site presently at that domain is all about dating... "To build a .deb package just follow this guide on how to notice if your partner is cheating on you" o_0)

Answer (score 5):

***Heed the warning below if you're dealing with a production system!***

---

You can install node.js through `apt-get`.

```
# echo deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main \
    > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sid.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get install nodejs
```

**WARNING:** That being said, you should probably not do this since you're installing software from Debian's development branch (Sid). This warning should especially be heeded if you're dealing with a production machine as well!!!

Comment: Should be said that mixing repositories of different Debian versions can lead to problems, that the user should be ready to face.

Comment: mixing repositories not lead to huge problem, but contain some version compatibility issues

Comment: Ok thanks - this will install from the unstable release, right? Is that not a problem?

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  Next time you upgrade your system everything will be upgraded to sid.  sid is unstable, not good for production, and it is only suitable for Debian experts.  Sid breaks a lot.  I would downvote this ten times if I could.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid mixing Debian versions (a recipe for pain!) by building your own .debs

https://github.com/mark-webster/node-debian

You can build .deb files for arbitrary versions of node.js, so you can install / upgrade / uninstall it easily. It's a bit quick and dirty, but at least it's something until the official Debian packages arrive in stable.

Comment: This package install `npm` too. Bytheway this is clean solution

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is available in official repo for Debian Sid and Jessie.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

If you don't have it in your main repository (the command didn't work), I'd recommend building from source, this way:

```
sudo apt-get install python g++ make checkinstall
mkdir ~/src && cd $_
wget -N http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*
./configure
checkinstall   #remove the "v" in front of the version number in the dialog!
sudo dpkg -i node_*
```

Uninstall:

```
sudo dpkg -r node
```

In case you get a permission denied on the `node` executable, an alternative path might be:

```
umask 0022
./configure
make
checkinstall -D --umask 0022 --reset-uids --install=no
dpkg -i node_*.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest stable Node, you can install it from the package manager, then update it using `npm`:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm 
sudo npm update -g
```

This to be the simplest way of getting the latest version without expending too much effort.

Comment: I found that npm etc would be broken after doing an 'npm update -g' as they'd include "#!/usr/bin/env node" rather than "#!/usr/bin/env nodejs" (Debian Jessie). I think you're best off installing from source, especially if you're going to allow npm to update itself globally (which chucks stuff into /usr/local/)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I have found the solution for this. 
If you are facing issues like [this](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/532)
Do not use the nodesource script to install nodejs on Debian. 
The script from nodesource should work fine on host systems, but it is affecting LXC/Docker containers in my experience.

do the following things manually to install the desired nodejs version installed

For your particular version of Debian/Ubuntu add the respective line to your sources.list file
release name would be the codename for your release of Debian/Ubuntu

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x/ <release name> main
```

add the repository key

```
curl --silent https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then do

`apt update` and

`apt install nodejs`
Let me know, if this was helpful to you. Thanks